# MYSQL_PWD and access denied

Tags: mysql

My system monitoring program isn't working anymore since upgrading from Ubuntu Server 14.04 to 16.04 with MySQL 5.6 to 5.7. It performs the following command:

```
mysqladmin -u statuser extended-status
```

It also sets the MYSQL_PWD environment variable for that process to the required password. The error message however is:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'statuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

When I try it interactively, it works fine:

```
mysqladmin -u statuser -p extended-status
(type in the password)
```

When I try to reproduce the tool's behaviour like this, it also fails:

```
MYSQL_PWD='********' mysqladmin -u statuser extended-status
```

So isn't MYSQL_PWD supported anymore? But it says "using password: YES" so it must have noticed my environment variable. It just doesn't seem to read it right.

Comment: What happens if you try to use `MYSQL_PWD='xxx' mysql -u statuser -p`

Comment: Maybe the easiest solution would be to store the password in some other way. The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html) describe multiple ways, and expressively say that using the `MYSQL_PWD` env variable is discouraged.

Comment: If I set the variable and the -p parameter, I need to type in the password. If I just press Enter then, it says "access denided, using password: NO"

Comment: Thanks I was trying to see if the MYSQL_PWD works for regular mysql client, which it doesn't appear to be working. Can you try making a new user with a very simple password no spaces and try setting that like `MYSQL_PWD=abc123 mysql -u newuser` I'm thinking some kind of quote trimming has changed

Comment: That is already a separate user for this statistics purpose. The password does not contain spaces. I've now changed it to pass the password as command line argument, for the "insecure" but not "extremely insecure" option. It prints a warning into my terminal from the background, but that won't bother me once I get that tool running as a service again. (Stupid upstart has been replaced by systemd, too... As if Ubuntu knew their special solution wouldn't last long.)

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddies I used these commands and it solved my issue:

```
mysql -uroot -p -hlocalhost
sudo service mysql restart
mysql -u root -p
```

Hope it should relieve you the agony

Comment: Can't downvote. What does this answer have to do with my question?